# inserting data into postgresql from matlab

Tags: sql, database, matlab, postgresql

I am trying to insert data into a table I have in postgresql.

This is my approach:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.wav', 'Select track')
s = strcat(PathName, FileName);

%info = id3parse(path); %s was in bracket

info = audioinfo(s); % info.SampleRate; gives sample rate etc

Track_Info = cell(1,8); %create a cell array

    try
        id = '1'; 
        Track_Info(1,1) = cellstr(id); %convert to cell array of strings
    catch
    end
    try
        title = info.Title;
        Track_Info(1,2) = cellstr(title);
    catch
    end
    try
        artist = info.Artist;
        Track_Info(1,3) = cellstr(artist);
    catch
    end
    try
        album = 'Default';
        Track_Info(1,4) = cellstr(album);
    catch
    end
    try
        genre = 'Default';
        Track_Info(1,5) = cellstr(genre);
    catch
    end
    try
        bpm = '100';
        Track_Info(1,6) = cellstr(bpm);
    catch
    end
    try
        duration = '1:00';
        Track_Info(1,7) = cellstr(duration);
    catch
    end
    try
        musickey = 'Am';
        Track_Info(1,8) = cellstr(musickey);
    catch
    end

celldisp(Track_Info); %check contents of Track_Info

Track_Info_Test = {'"1"','"Title"','"Joe"','"Album"','"House"','"120"', '"4.00"', '"Am"'};


conn =   database('harmonicmixing','postgres','jurgen','org.postgresql.Driver','jdbc:postgresql://localhost/harmonicmixing');
if(isempty(conn.message))

 disp('database connected')

else
 disp('cannot connect')

 disp(conn.message);

 return
end


colnames = { '"id"','"title"','"artist"', '"album"', '"genre"', '"bpm"', '"duration"', '"musickey"' };
fastinsert(conn, '"musiccollection"', colnames, Track_Info_Test); 
commit(conn);
close(conn);
```

Track_Info is the actual cell array which will contain the information about a particular track.

However in the code as shown above, i am using another cell array Track_info_test in which the values are hard coded as it doesn't matter for now how I get the information. What I want to do is just manage to insert the data into the table. I've tried many things and the code as shown above is just as it looks right now.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error using database/fastinsert (line 285)
Java exception occurred:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "musiccollection"
("id","title","artist","album","genre","bpm","duration","musickey") VALUES (
'"1"','"Title"','"Joe"','"Album"','"House"','"120"','"4.00"','"Am"') was      aborted.  Call
getNextException to see the cause.
at
           org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(Abstrac tJdbc2Statement.java:2762)
        at
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1999)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:421)
at
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2929)

Error in add_file_to_DB (line 73)
fastinsert(conn, '"musiccollection"', colnames, Track_Info_Test);
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong? Alternatives? Something I'm missing? new to matlab so the obvious is not obvious for me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're inserting numbers as text

Comment: that shouldnt make a difference and in fact i tried to fix it and it still didn't work. in a string you can hold a number if you like as far as i know, for ex. a telephone number. or a part of an address can be a number

Comment: yes, you can hold numbers in a string/text format field but not opposite. It should work as soon as   '"1"', ... ,'"Title"',
'"Joe"', '"Album"', '"House"','"120"','"4.00"' becomes something like
'1','"Title"','"Joe"','"Album"','"House"','120','4.00'. Single ' ' is fine
for postgres numerical formats, "" - no

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the cell array into a table first.

Comment: it worked once or twice and the same error again. lol, either I'm crazy or I have no idea what's happening

Comment: I don't know matlab but is it possible instead of  cellstr(id) put something like cellint(id) ? the same for 2 other numerical par-s or more precisely cellint() and cellfloat()